# Azure apple push notifcation certification

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am hosting asp.net mvc 4 app in azure web site.

Where can I store the apple/windows push notification p12 cert?

Should I create a folder, and how can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Include the cert as content then load it before initializing the APN.  You can "load" it with `X509Certificate2` and `X509CertificateCollection2` and use it with `SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient`  For an example, see http://simonguest.com/2011/04/21/using-apple-push-notifications-from-windows-azure/